# What does "A.fn.A.init {}" mean?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create an object A, so I write like this:

```
A = function() {
}
A.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

The result of `new A.prototype.init()` is `A.init {}`.
When I create an alias for A.prototype like this:

```
A = function() {
}
A.as = A.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

The result turned out to be `A.as.A.init {}` instead of `A.init {}`.
Why? How does `this` work?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: "*The result of `new A.prototype.init()`*" Don't do that. Create `new A` instances if that is what you want, and drop `init` methods.

Answer (score 1):

> What does “A.fn.A.init {}” mean in javascript?

It doesn't really mean anything. Neither the console API nor the output it generates are standardized. Browsers will apply some implementation specific heuristic to determine the "name" or "class" of an object (they'll likely look at the `constructor` property but apparently are doing more than that).

In both cases, `this` will refer to a new object that inherts from `A.prototype.init.prototype`, no matter which name the console chooses to show you.